# Servo motor won't work for a specific code

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, interrupt

I have written a code with interrupts to control the servo but my servos are not working. One is meant to work with interrupt but the other one has to simply move but it is also not working. Even the serial window shows that the code is working properly ut the servos aren't moving I have checked both my servos with same connections and Sweep example of Arduino and both work fine.

```
#include <TimerOne.h>                                 // Header file for TimerOne library
#include <Servo.h>
#define trigPin 12                                    // Pin 12 trigger output
#define echoPin 2                                     // Pin 2 Echo input

#define echo_int 0                                    // Interrupt id for echo pulse

#define TIMER_US 50                                   // 50 uS timer duration 
#define TICK_COUNTS 4000                              // 200 mS worth of timer ticks

volatile long echo_start = 0;                         // Records start of echo pulse 
volatile long echo_end = 0;                           // Records end of echo pulse
volatile long echo_duration = 0;                      // Duration - difference between end and start
volatile int trigger_time_count = 0;                  // Count down counter to trigger pulse time
volatile long range_flasher_counter = 0;              // Count down counter for flashing distance LED


int sound = 250;

Servo servo1; //Servos
Servo servo2;


const int button1 = 10; //Buttons
const int button2 = 8;
const int button3 = 13;
const byte interruptPin = 3;
int pos;


void setup() {
  servo1.attach(9); // servo for arm
  servo2.attach(5); // servo for base
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);                           // Trigger pin set to output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);                            // Echo pin set to input
                      // Onboard LED pin set to output
  
  Timer1.initialize(TIMER_US);                        // Initialise timer 1
  Timer1.attachInterrupt( timerIsr );                 // Attach interrupt to the timer service routine 
  attachInterrupt(echo_int, echo_interrupt, CHANGE);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin),Metal_detected, HIGH);

  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 


  servo1.write(0); // These will make the servos move to the mapped angles
  servo2.write(90);
  
  distance_checking();
  if(digitalRead(button1) == HIGH)
  {
   
      while(digitalRead(button2) == LOW)
        {
          Serial.println("Entering Sweeping mode");
       for (pos = 30; pos <= 150; pos += 1)
       { Serial.print("Angle is :");
         Serial.println(pos);
         servo2.write(pos);              
         distance_checking();
         //delay(0.1);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
         if(digitalRead(button2) == HIGH)
          { 
            Serial.print("Exiting Sweeping");
            goto label;}
          }
          for (pos = 150; pos >= 30; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degree
          Serial.print("Angle is :");
          Serial.println(pos);
          servo2.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
          distance_checking();
          //delay(0.1);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
          if(digitalRead(button2) == HIGH)
          {
            goto label;
            Serial.print("Exiting Sweeping");}
          }

 }
 }
//reset th
label:
  if(digitalRead(button2) == HIGH){ 
    
    servo1.write(0);
    servo2.write(90);
    Serial.println("press the sweeping button to enter sweeeping mode");
    delay(300);
  }

} 


void distance_checking()
{ 

if (echo_duration/58 <= 20) 
{
Serial.println("the servo angle is 30");
servo1.write(30);
delay(1500);
}

else {
servo1.write(0);
}

delay(500);
}





void Metal_detected()
{if(digitalRead(button2) == LOW)
{delay(5000);
  Serial.print("Metal detected at servo angle:");
Serial.println(servo2.read());
servo1.write(servo1.read());
servo2.write(servo2.read());
Serial.println("Motion is stopped");
Serial.println("Press reset to go to the home position");


}
//while(digitalRead(button2) == HIGH)
// {
//  Serial.print("Reseting");
//  return 0;}
 }
void timerIsr()
{
    trigger_pulse();                                 // Schedule the trigger pulses
                             // Flash the onboard LED distance indicator
}

// --------------------------
// trigger_pulse() called every 50 uS to schedule trigger pulses.
// Generates a pulse one timer tick long.
// Minimum trigger pulse width for the HC-SR04 is 10 us. This system
// delivers a 50 uS pulse.
// --------------------------
void trigger_pulse()
{
      static volatile int state = 0;                 // State machine variable

      if (!(--trigger_time_count))                   // Count to 200mS
      {                                              // Time out - Initiate trigger pulse
         trigger_time_count = TICK_COUNTS;           // Reload
         state = 1;                                  // Changing to state 1 initiates a pulse
      }
    
      switch(state)                                  // State machine handles delivery of trigger pulse
      {
        case 0:                                      // Normal state does nothing
            break;
        
        case 1:                                      // Initiate pulse
           digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);              // Set the trigger output high
           state = 2;                                // and set state to 2
           break;
        
        case 2:                                      // Complete the pulse
        default:      
           digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);               // Set the trigger output low
           state = 0;                                // and return state to normal 0
           break;
     }
}

// --------------------------
// echo_interrupt() External interrupt from HC-SR04 echo signal. 
// Called every time the echo signal changes state.
//
// Note: this routine does not handle the case where the timer
//       counter overflows which will result in the occassional error.
// --------------------------
void echo_interrupt()
{
  switch (digitalRead(echoPin))                     // Test to see if the signal is high or low
  {
    case HIGH:                                      // High so must be the start of the echo pulse
      echo_end = 0;                                 // Clear the end time
      echo_start = micros();                        // Save the start time
      break;
      
    case LOW:                                       // Low so must be the end of hte echo pulse
      echo_end = micros();                          // Save the end time
      echo_duration = echo_end - echo_start;        // Calculate the pulse duration
      break;
  }
}
```

I tested my motors with this code one by one and they worked absolutely fine:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is really hard to follow and the indention is all over the place. Also I don't understand the reason why you are using a timer interrupt and an external interrupt just for reading the ultrasonic sensor, but then using many long `delay()` calls. Can you please describe how exactly you want the code to behave?

Comment: I think the Servo library uses Timer1. Thus using both at the same time can lead to problems

Comment: The thing is that I am using both interrupts of Arduino Uno. One for the data from Ultrasonic and one for the other signal that I have to attach to pin3. The code works the way that one servo keeps sweeping to the angle between 30 and 150 until the distance from the ultrasonic is greater than 20cm ,as the distance gets less it has to follow the function "distance_checking"